# How can i create cart using session in php?

Tags: php, session

Here I am trying to add the product to cart on click of `add to cart`  button.

Here I have button `add to cart`. Now I want to add the this item to cart, using session.

But in this case the session will already be started I want to just add the items to cart. How can I add the items to cart?

code:
This is what I have in add to cart button

```
echo "<a href='index.php?action=add&product_id=$product_id' class='buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> Add to cart</a>";
```

or do I have to submit form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that the session cart is already made and that it is an array of ID's. Also, you will need to protect it better.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && isset($_GET['product_id'])){
        if($_GET['action'] == "add"){
            $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_GET['product_id'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: How can i save multiple id's? currently i am able to save only one value.

Comment: Where you create the session variable, declare it an array. $_SESSION['cart'] = array(); You can then access each ID like this: $_SESSION['cart'][0] or $_SESSION['cart'][1] etc